# How to set the y-coordinate (in pixels) of the current line

Tags: buffers, window, fonts, images, scrolling

I want to scroll the buffer so that the the current line is, say, 300
pixels from the beginning of the window.

Something like this:

```
. \ 
. | (300 pixels)
. /
| <-- (current line)
```

Any ideas?

Note that the buffer may contain figures and different font sizes, so scrolling a fixed number of text lines won't do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the vertical scroll parameter of your current *window* (and other windows, too) with pixel precision:

```
(set-window-vscroll nil 300 t)
```

This will however not work with any value greater than the frame height though.  [I've had to hand in a bug where Emacs hangs up for certain display engine configurations upon doing this even](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19464).